# Writing a peer-review suggestions letter for a journal editor

Tags: peer-review

I am submitting my review for a journal but they ask for a letter with peer review suggestions (3), but it is not templete, and i am not sure if I can suggest any peer for the review or they have a specific list.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think they are asking for the names of people, but for your suggestions for the paper. Unless the wording is pretty specific otherwise.

Comment: @Buffy I think OP is submitting a review article, rather than a peer review of another paper. They're asking for suggestions for peer reviewers.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you're asking about how to respond to a request for potential reviewers by the editor.

It is what it looks like on face value - you suggest potential reviewers, which the editors may or may not use. There is no "list" to choose from. You can suggest anyone as long as they have the technical know-how to review your paper. You should avoid suggesting people who might have a conflict of interest with you (so e.g. other members of your department are excluded).

Comment: Actually, if your interpretation is correct, it might also be more general and the editor is just trying to build up a "stable" of reviewers. In that case, conflict of interest becomes less of an issue. And even if not, conflict of interest seems an odd thing to bring up here. The reviewer isn't in competition with the author.